# Looking for a simple database with graphical interface for personal use, under Linux

Tags: gui, application, database

I am a former MacOS user, and I was using FileMaker, to organize one or two databases for my research work.
I am looking for something similar, to be used under Linux.

I would need something local, with frontend and backend together in the same application.
Ideally, I would like something fully graphical, or with minimal need for code writing.

I know about SQL, but it would be an overkill, I expect a size in the range of 100 records, so search speed would not be an issue.

I wold need a "layout" or "view" where the records are shown in a list (one record per row), but also a "layout" or "view" where a "page" or "window" is shown for each record.

Also, I would like the possibility to add new fields to the record design "on the go", i.e.  without creating a new database but modifying the existing one.

Here are few examples of applications:

• A database of books,  with a picture of the cover shown in the "page view" (possibly adding the image should be done with drag-and-drop, or copy-and-paste).

• A database of people, with the option of a picture field with face and/or business card.

• A mixed database of "events", or "ideas".

Comment: The closest thing I have found so far is the database of LibreOffice, but it is really "ugly", everything seems based on tables. I need to visualize records, with graphic fields (pictures).

Comment: I **think** libreOffice Base (which is the descendant of Sun StarBase, from the days of StarOffice), which you've already found, *can* deal with image assets in appropriate fields. I've never tried it though. "Ugly" is a fair description – it's really not moved much since the Lotus Office from ~ 1997 (and which you might recognize as what Microsoft Office pre-2003 feels like).

Comment: You can have a look at Kexi (which should be easily available from whatever Linux distro you're using from its package manager), which is the same "idea" as StarBase/OpenOffice Base/LibreOffice Base, but maybe a bit less old-timey. In exchange, the code hasn't seen any release in the last ~4 years.

Comment: but regarding your three examples, *do you really want to design these yourself*: 1. Your database of books: If you want to deal with many ebooks, `calibre` is really nice. If you deal more with a scientific library, especially if you want to manage things to cite in papers etc, `Zotero` does a really nice job (and integrates with Firefox for one-click book/reference-saving, as well!) 2. Your database of people: There's personal information managers out there. I don't know your usage requirements for one, though! 3. "Mixed database" Sounds more like a job for `Joplin` or `zim`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will be better here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @MarcusMüller, I like Joplin and zim, they may be what I was looking for! :)
I will try them for a bit, and decide.
About Calibre and Zotero, I know them, but they are not what I need: I don't need to archive the actual books, but just "records" about them, and I need a flexible structure, with (only) the fields that are relevant to me :)
Same story for the "address book" application.